# Retrieving variable from outside completion block Parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview, pfquery

I have an app that contains a table view. The table view is populated by data pulled from Parse. To get the number of rows that I want the TableView to be populated with, I query parse.

```
    var activeGamesCurrentUser = 0

    gamesQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (count, error) -> Void in
            let countedInt = Int(UInt32(count))
            self.activeGamesCurrentUser = countedInt
        })
```

But, when I attempt to return activeGamesCurrentUser for the number of rows, it is always 0 because the variable doesn't update outside of the completion block. If I print "countedInt" inside of the block, it is a number greater than 0.

I do not want to solve the problem like this:

```
    var count = gamesQuery.countObjects()
    activeGamesCurrentUser = count
```

The reason for this is because "countObjects()" is synchronous and will continue running in the foreground forever. Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here is the full method:

```
var activeGamesCurrentUser = 0

func getRowNumber() {
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil && finished == true {
        currentUserObjectId = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

        let challengedQuery = PFQuery(className: "Games")
        challengedQuery.whereKey("challenged", equalTo:     currentUserObjectId)

        let challengerQuery = PFQuery(className: "Games")
        challengerQuery.whereKey("challenger", equalTo: (currentUser?.objectId)!)

        let gamesQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([challengedQuery, challengerQuery])

        gamesQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (count, error) -> Void in
            let countedInt = Int(UInt32(count))
            self.activeGamesCurrentUser = countedInt
        })

        }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()


     getRowNumber()
     }
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        

     return activeGamesCurrentUser
     }
```

Comment: After you have retrieved your table data in the background you need to call `tableView.reloadData()` in order to tell the tableview that the data has changed

Comment: I do call tableView.reloadData() already. My issue is not in retrieving the data to populate the rows, but in finding how many rows the table view should have. I can't find a way to get the variable "activeGamesCurrentUser" out of the completion block without its value going back to 0. @Paulw11

Comment: This code will set the property.  When are you trying to access its value in relation to this closure? ie. How does the code know that is printing the value know that the closure has completed?

Comment: Post your full method, with the `return activeGamesCurrentUser`

Comment: I made the edit @t4nhpt

Comment: I print the variable within the closure. I want to access the number that was queried within the closure, outside of the closure. @Paulw11

Comment: Yes, but you need to make sure you access it *after* the closure has completed.  Generally you will call some function, such as `reloadData` in the closure so that the tableview knows that the number of rows has changed.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Thanks, that worked. I thought that reload data only applied to the data you were populating the table with. If you put that in an answer I'll mark it as solved @Paulw11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things -

**First**, always access class properties inside the block with a weak reference to self.

**Second**, reload table once you are done updating your model.

```
weak var aBlockSelf = self

gamesQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (count, error) -> Void in
            let countedInt = Int(UInt32(count))
            aBlockSelf.activeGamesCurrentUser = countedInt
            aBlockSelf.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

Comment: You don't always need a weak self reference; only if there is a chance of a retain cycle, which there isn't in this case.

Comment: @Paulw11 but in this case by not making the reference weak you end up retaining the controller even after it has been popped off the stack(if the request takes long). Making it weak prevents this

Comment: In this case it won't matter, but in some cases you may well want the view controller to hang around until the network operation completes because there may be other work to be done, such as after saving.  You shouldn't *always* use a weak reference and in most cases not using it won't have any greater effect than prolonging an object lifetime slightly